# Logshipping between SQL Server 2008 R2 (CLustered Instance) and SQL Server 2012 SP3 Always On Instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

We are migrating application from `SQL 2008R2` (Clustered Instance) to SQL `Server 2012SP3` Always On instance. It's a Critical application. So we don't have much down time to do the migration & Cutover.

To save some valuable time I would have think to configure Log Shipping between SQL Server 2008 R2(Clustered Instance) & SQL Server 2012 SP3 Always On. As per my plan I will configure 1 day prior to the actual cutover. Monitor till the actual cutover.

### My Plan:-

1) Primary Node will be Current production : SQL Server 2008R2 Enterprise Edition and Secondary would be SQL Server 2012 SP3 Enterprise Edition [Always On]. Both the instances are clustered. SQL 2012 instance is the new dedicated instance for Application.

2) We can configure log shipping Between SQL Server 2008R2 (Clustered Instance)and SQL Server 2012 AlwaysOn.

3) Configure Log shipping as per the standard procedure. I would think about the jobs of the Secondary Instance. If any fail over happened then jobs will not be in secondary AlwaysOn Instance.

4) During the configuration we while restoring to 2012 Instance should not be added to Availability Group. I don't need the DB to be added into the Availability Group.

5) The SQL 2012 standby database would be tested as Pre-Prod Environment. As this is very critical application, test would take longer time.

6) Once the application Configured & tested as Pre-Prod then we will schedule the actual downtime for cutover.

7) Then break the log shipping & restore the final log after downtime started to SQL Server 2012 Instance with recovery. It will reduce the entire backup restore process.

8) Add the database to the Availability Group for HA-DR & synced in SQL 2012 instance.

9) Then map the entire application to the Current SQL 2012 AlwaysOn Environment.

10) It will save lot of time during actual migration. Then start the post migration steps.

I assume it's feasible to configure Log Shipping as mentioned above. 
Please let me know, expert suggestions.

Comment: I'm not a big expert, but I'm concerned that step 8 on a big DB can take a long time and it's in your downtime window. Maybe you should consider having the DB on an AG already.

Answer (score 0):

Log shipping is a technology based on transnational log backup. The log shipping database is a read only database and can't be change.

your first SQL server is SQL Server 2008R2 and the Second SQL Server is SQL Server 2012. SQL Server update database files when want to restore backup of lower version. this means your database backup must be update because source of database is SQL Server 2008R2 and Destination of database is SQL Server 2012.

Log shipping create readonly database and can't be update database (In other word you can create log shipping database from sql server 2008r2 and SQL Server 2012).